# What is the meaning of Jittering in Orange3? What function does it serve?

Tags: data-analysis, scatter-plot, orange

What is the meaning of Jittering in Orange3? What function does it serve?
In the Scatter Plot widget there is a slide bar option called 'Jittering', what does it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jitter):

> jitter is the deviation from true [...] signal

The use in Orange, as [this article](https://thomasleeper.com/Rcourse/Tutorials/jitter.html) neatly sums up, refers to random plotted perturbations of true data so as to more clearly reveal the *density* of *discrete/nominal* data points.

The same plot without (left) and with (right) jittering:

[image: two random scatter plots without (left) and with (right) jittering applies]